# Overriding atributes in chef

Tags: json, chef-infra

I configured some of the attributes in my cookbook. Later, I thought to modify that one of the attributes of my cookbook. I tried overriding from chef server by editing Node specific attributes from chef server(UI of chef server). I added

```html
"cookbook_name": {
   "jdbc_connection": "jdbc:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 },
```

Later I thought to edit one more attribute which downloads different plugins. this is my default attribute is

```html
default['cookbook_name']['attribute'] = %w(
a
b
c
d
)
```

so to override above attributeI gave below attribute in specific to node attributes in chef server

```
"cookbook_name": {"attribut": "['a','b']"}
```

my purpose is not to install all the artifacts which is a,b,c,d that I defined in cookbook but I want to install only artifacts a and b.  even after defining `"cookbook_name": {"attribut": "['a','b']"}` in specific to node attribute my chef-client is taking default attribute other than node specific attribute that I defined in chef server which install all rather than a and b. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You typo'd `attribute`, but more importantly `"['a','b']"` is not an array, it's a string. You can find more information about JSON formatting at http://json.org/.